# Extract Regex Values (Regex Match) in Blue Prism

Tags: regex, regex-group, blueprism

In Blue Prism, I need to identify specific elements of a Data Item (text), in order to use the information later in my process.

The text string reads:

> REKVISITION_NR: 1234567 Dato: 23-07-2018 Rekvirent: ABC, DEF GHI, JKL 60, 8600 MNO Sted: JKL 60, 8600 MNO, Kl.:14:00:00, Bestilt_tid: 60 min Tolkensnavn: PQR STU Koert_fra: VXY , 8600 Silkeborg Vedr.: Z CPR: 123456-7890 Sprog: Arabisk Type: Personlig fremmøde Godkendt: 24-07-2018

As you can see, each element has these traits (e.g. ***Kl.***:14:00:00 or ***Sprog***: Arabisk):

- A string name (starting with an uppercase letter)
- Optionally, a period character (.)
- A colon character (:)
- Optionally, a space character ( )
- The value part of the string
- A space character ( ), which is followed by the next element.

I believe I should use the Business Object *Utility - Strings*' action *Extract Regex Values*, but have not sucessfully been able to match any data that can be copied into the *Named Values*-collection.
However, I have found that `([A-Z])\w+\.?: ?(\w(\d\-){0,3})+` brings me some of the way in terms of matching.
I want the solution to copy the field names and values into the Named Values collection generated by the action.

Final notes: I am using Blue Prism 6.2.1, and the action's underlying code is based on [VB.net's Regex.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Will these fields always be in the same order and always present?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that, @esqew. But I hope for something general.

Comment: I have created a regex object that I use over the standard one. You can find a copy here: https://github.com/Unknown008/BluePrism-Customs/tree/master/Utility%20-%20Regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to be missing are the actual Named Groups. To capture the values in a Blue Prism collection, you need to make sure that you assign proper group names like this:

```
(?<YourGroupName>[A-Z])
```

Here's the regex pattern that you may use, although you need to verify if it really works for your case in all possible scenarios.

```
(?<Name>\b\S*?):\s(?<Value>.*?)\s*(?=(?:\b\S*?:\s)|$)
```

You can also check and test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dhecWA/1/).

EDIT: But please be aware that Blue Prism's original code for extracting multiple values to a collection is barely usable, you may be better off at modifying it or creating your own. For example, what I would expect from such an action is a collection where each row will be a pattern match, with each column being a named group. Sadly, that's not how the default action works.

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Thanks! This was a big leap in the right direction. But I still cannot get it to pass the name and values to the collection. I have tried with a collection with no data, as well as with initial values similar to the regex groups ( https://i.imgur.com/Mfb2cGs.png ). Neither seems to work. Can you provide me with screenshots of your collection and regex action?

Comment: You need to actually put the 'Name' and 'Value' into the collection initial values (group names) for the column 'Name' instead of the text values. This has a downside, however, as it will only give you the first match. To achieve what you are looking for you either need to modify the .NET code, have a rigid and less general Regex pattern, or have an overkill of a BP process logic to do some pattern generation on the fly and looping to get each match. If you can do a bit of .NET I would advise the first option, if the incoming data is of the same structure then do the second one.

Comment: Yes, it certainly looks like Blue Prism has implemented this feature poorly, @Marek Stejskal. I am still unable to retrieve anything beyound . The Action and Collection look like this:
https://i.imgur.com/KgDnGsR.png (Action's inputs)
https://i.imgur.com/uVewHTF.png (Action's outputs)
https://i.imgur.com/tDpFzev.png (Collection's Initial Values)
https://i.imgur.com/ACSRWRO.png (Collection's Current Values - note that the Name regex-group is set as a Value in the collection)
Can you provide similar screenshots (perhaps add them to your answer above)?

Comment: I probably made it slightly more confusing by naming my Regex groups 'Name' and 'Value' as well. I added a picture to make the usage clearer. Please note that this action returns only a single (first) match.